# Remove a line from .bashrc using a bash script

Tags: linux, bash, file

I've got a bash install script that adds a line to my `.bashrc` file using the following syntax:

```
echo "export MY_APP_INSTALL_PATH="$directory"" >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
```

For the equivalent uninstall script I want to remove the line that was appended to my `.bashrc` file but I can't find a way to do so.

Is there a way?

Comment: If thats the only line you add, you can just truncate the last line out of the file.

Comment: Your install script is broken (the quotes are awful). It should be: `echo "export MY_APP_INSTALL_PATH=\"$directory\"" >> ~/.bashrc`; and even then, we hope that the expansion `$directory` doesn't contain dangerous characters. It would be better written as: `printf 'export MY_APP_INSTALLPATH=%q\n' "$directory" >> ~/.bashrc`.

Comment: @123 If I had altered my .bashrc after running this install script, I'd be pretty unhappy to have the uninstall script remove whatever line happened to be last.

Comment: How robust does this need to be? Are you just going to run it on your own bashrc? Or is this something you're going to ship to customers? Customers who might call and complain when they're locked out of their account because your uninstaller trashed their .bashrc?

Answer (score 4):

You could do with something like:

```
path_to_purge="MY_APP_INSTALL_PATH"

# Remove it from .bashrc
sed -i "/^export ${path_to_purge}=/d" ~/.bashrc

# unset it in the environment
unset ${path_to_purge}
unset path_to_purge
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this usage of `sed`'s `-i` option is not portable between GNU and BSD versions of `sed`. If you want it to work on BSD as well, specify a backup extension (`sed -i.bkp ...`).

Answer (score 3):

```
$ cat file.txt
Hello world
this is a
simple file with some lines
$ sed '/this is a/d' file.txt
Hello world
simple file with some lines
```

Your `sed` might even support the `-i` flag which makes the changes directly in file instead of printing the result out on stdout.

How it works:
sed searches for the text between the `/` and then deletes these lines